# Slider seek position pygamemixer

Tags: python, pygame, pyqt5

I can make the QSlider update with a QTimer and setvalue of the position of Pygame mixer for MP3. However, I would like to be able to seek back and forth as well as keep accurate time.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize,Qt,QTimer
import pygame
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3

pygame.init()

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(791, 125)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.timeSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.timeSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 30, 421, 22))
        self.timeSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.timeSlider.setObjectName("timeSlider")
        self.playBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.playBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 75, 23))
        self.playBtn.setObjectName("playBtn")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 791, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.timer=QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.playBtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Play"))
        self.playBtn.clicked.connect(self.play)
        self.timeSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.slider_changed)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.slider_changed)

    def play(self):
        pygame.mixer.music.load('C:/mp3/audio/Your Love.mp3')
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def slider_changed(self):
        song_mutagen=MP3('C:/mp3/audio/Your Love.mp3')
        songLength = song_mutagen.info.length
        self.timeSlider.setMaximum(songLength)
        current_time=int(pygame.mixer.music.get_pos()/1000)
        self.timeSlider.setValue(current_time)
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out finally. Adding 1 integer per second to the **self.timeSlider.value()** when the QTimer calls the **keep_time** function allows me to modify the slider instead of locking it down to the set value.  I am adding this if it might help anyone out that would like to create their own MP3 player.  I am sure there are other ways to do it, I am all ears for this.

up top change **self.timeSlider.sliderMoved.connect(self.slider_changed)**(originally .valueChanged) to send the position of the slider to the slider_changed function

#################################################################################

```
 def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.playBtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Play"))
        self.playBtn.clicked.connect(self.play)
        self.timeSlider.sliderMoved.connect(self.slider_changed)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.keep_time)
    def play(self):
        pygame.mixer.music.load('C:/mp3/audio/Your Love.mp3')
        self.timeSlider.setValue(0)
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        self.timer.start()
    def slider_changed(self,position):
        song_mutagen=MP3('C:/mp3/audio/Your Love.mp3')
        songLength = song_mutagen.info.length
        self.timeSlider.setMaximum(songLength)
        self.timeSlider.blockSignals(True)
        pygame.mixer.music.set_pos(position)
        self.timeSlider.blockSignals(False)
        
####Qtimer calls this function every second to update the slider starting from 0 
    def keep_time(self):
        self.timeSlider.setMinimum(0)
        song_mutagen=MP3('C:/mp3/audio/Your Love.mp3')
        songLength = song_mutagen.info.length
        self.timeSlider.setMaximum(songLength)
        next_time = self.timeSlider.value() +1 #Add 1 to the Slider value each pass
        self.timeSlider.setValue(next_time)      #Set the Value to next time value
           
        if next_time >= songLength:
             self.timer.stop()
```